# How to extract the prime numbers generated by RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, cryptography, primes, rsacryptoserviceprovider

The below code is attempting to get the two RSA prime numbers generated by `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. I'm testing `primeq` for primality and it always turns up to be non prime. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(384);
var p = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
var primeq = new BigInteger(p.Q);
```

Comment: `RSAParameters` fields are returned in big-endian order. The `BigInteger` byte[] constructor expects a little-endian order argument. So reverse the order, and don't forget to curse Microsoft for their carelessness and stupidity.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - I don't think it was carelessness or stupidity. Microsoft OSes and software runs on machines that are little-endian. Even the ARM gadgets are run with the CPU in little endian mode. it was a matter of simplicity and efficiency. Microsoft could do a better job of documenting it.

Comment: @jww: The carelessness and stupidity come from using little endian in one place and big endian in another. And the endianness of the CPU should have little relevance to the endianness of an exported big integer representation. Finally, I still can't find anything in the documentation of the RSAParameters fields that mentions the endianness. That's just amazing.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - Check it out... Microsoft is documenting it better: [cryptoapi little endian msdn](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+cryptoapi+little+endian+msdn). I wish I could find that article that discussed the design decisions for you. Even OpenSSL does it for simplicity and efficiency (see `BN_bn2lebinpad` and `BN_bin2lbn` docs). I really don't see the carelessness or stupidity. They were design decisions to achieve certain goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this problem myself. I have found that there are in fact two issues:

1. First, `BigInteger` uses different endianess from the `RSACryptoServiceProvider`
2. `BigInteger` is signed and uses two's compliment notation, whereas RSA keys are unsigned integers.

To solve this I would modify your code as follows:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(384);
var p = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
var primeq = new BigInteger(p.Q.Reverse().Concat(new Byte[1]).ToArray());
```

This was tested with the following code:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
    var a = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(a.P.Reverse().Concat(new byte[1]).ToArray());
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(a.Q.Reverse().Concat(new byte[1]).ToArray());
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(a.Modulus.Reverse().Concat(new byte[1]).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(p * q == n);
}
```